# How long is "for a while"?

Tags: meaning

A friend messaged me with "I'm going offline for a while". I want to know what for a while means, in terms of time of course. I know it probably depends on the context too.

Comment: It always depends entirely and only upon the context. "A while" has no specific or defined meaning as a measure of duration.

Comment: "A while" as a duration of time is purely dependent upon the context. In general though, perhaps it is used to describe a longer period of time, than a shorter one. The actial amount of time though could be of any length.

Answer (score 2):

How long is a piece of string?

There are a number of expressions used to speak imprecisely about time.

Figuratively "a moment" or "a second" would usually mean "as short a time as possible".  Saying "I'm going offline for a moment" suggests that you won't have time do anything while I'm gone. Whereas "a while" implies a longer period, and you will have time do something.

But it is deliberately vague, and could be anything from a few minutes to days. (or even years given the right context).

Comment: Heck, even years — or for the foreseeable future. Anything, really, with the right context.